# What is different between RNN output and rule based output?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I am new in machine learning and i got a question , I am [following this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-by-example-using-tensorflow-feb0c1968537) , I read about LSTM and RNN. i use the code provided by tutorial and run it , it completed the training and now i gave some strings for testing :

[Training data is this :](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/roatienza/Deep-Learning-Experiments/master/Experiments/Tensorflow/RNN/belling_the_cat.txt)

output is :

```
Iter= 20000, Average Loss= 0.531466, Average Accuracy= 84.60%
['the', 'sly', 'and'] - [treacherous] vs [treacherous]
Optimization Finished!
Elapsed time:  12.159853319327036 min
Run on command line.
    tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow/rnn_words
Point your web browser to: http://localhost:6006/
3 words: ,hello wow and
Word not in dictionary
3 words: mouse,mouse,mouse
3 words: mouse
3 words: mouse mouse mouse
mouse mouse mouse very well , but who is to bell the cat approaches the until will at one another and take mouse a receive some signal of her approach , we he easily escape
3 words: 3 words: had a general
had a general to proposal to make round the neck will all agree , said he easily at and enemy approaches to consider what common the case . you will all agree , said he
3 words: mouse mouse mouse
mouse mouse mouse very well , but who is to bell the cat approaches the until will at one another and take mouse a receive some signal of her approach , we he easily escape
3 words: what was cat
what was cat up and said he is all very well , but who is to bell the cat approaches the until will at one another and take mouse a receive some signal of her
3 words: mouse fear cat
Word not in dictionary
3 words: mouse tell cat
Word not in dictionary
mo3 words: mouse said cat
Word not in dictionary
3 words: mouse fear fear
Word not in dictionary
3 words: mouse ring bell
Word not in dictionary
m3 words: mouse ring ring
Word not in dictionary
3 words: mouse bell bell
mouse bell bell and general to make round the neck will all agree , said he easily at and enemy approaches to consider what common the case . you will all agree , said he
3 words: mouse and bell
mouse and bell this means we should always , but looked is young always , but looked is young always , but looked is young always , but looked is young always , but looked
3 words: mouse was bell
mouse was bell and said he is all very well , but who is to bell the cat approaches the until will at one another and take mouse a receive some signal of her approach
3 words:
```

Now what i am not getting , When i give three words it gives result something like which we can easily achieve via regular expression or rule based code using if-else like if input words in file then fetch some sentence previous or next sentences , What is special about this output , How its different ? Explain please

like sometimes it says , word not in dict , so if i have to give only those words which are in training file then its like its matching inout words in training data and fetching some result from file then we can do same thing with if else or in pure programming without any module then how's its different ?

Answer (score 0):

Your training dataset only has ~180 words, and is achieving a 84.6% (training) accuracy, so it is overfitting quite a bit. Essentially, the model is simply predicting the next most likely word based on the training data.

Usually language models are trained on much larger datasets, such as PTB or the 1B word benchmark. PTB is a small dataset, with 100,000 words, and the 1B word benchmark has 1 billion words.

RNN models have a limited vocabulary to allow words or characters to be encoded. The vocabulary size would depend on model. Most word models that train on PTB have a vocabulary size of 10,000, which is enough for most common words.